# Equivalent Java code for IMAP command. Escape characters issue

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, imap

I'm using IMAP protocol in Java to fetch email messages

Following is the IMAP command which I want to generate in Java

```
A SEARCH HEADER From "xyz.abc@gmail.com" ALL
```

following is the sudo java code

```
String header = "From";
String value = "\"xyz.abc@gmail.com\"";
SearchTerm searchTerm = new HeaderTerm(header,value);
```

But unfortunately above java code is generating wrong IMAP command , it's adding escape characters also

```
A SEARCH HEADER From "\"xyz.abc@gmail.com\"" ALL
```

How to generate double quotes properly in IMAP command ??

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes from the string `value`; JavaMail will quote the value as necessary:

```
String value = "xyz.abc@gmail.com";
```

Also, consider using [FromTerm](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/search/FromTerm.html) or [FromStringStream](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/search/FromStringTerm.html).